# can anyone say how sampling rate and framesize is realted?

Tags: c, audio

Can anyone say how sampling rate and framesize are related ?

I decoded a spx file to wav, with sampling rate of 10 kHz and at 16 bit. The frame size applied during the decoding process was 640. 
The decoded file is playable in vlc. But I want to play that file in Flex.

Flex supports rate of 44.1 kHz, 22.5 kHz and 11.2 kHz only. I want to increase the sampling rate during decoding process. I know how to do that in the code but I guess the framesize also should be increased. I don't know the dependency between these two. Can anyone help?

Comment: According to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5574, the Speex codec doesn't support 10 kHz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frame size and sampling rate are generally orthogonal concepts. They don't need to affect each other unless a particular format demands it.

For PCM .wav, the frame size will always be bits/channels * channels. In your case, 16 bits for mono, or 32 bits for stereo.

Also, there is no need to change the decoding frame size only because you later apply resampling.

Comment: Doesn't `bits/channels * channels` equal bits?

Comment: Think he means bits/channel * numchannels

Comment: you mean `bitsPerChannel * numChannels`?

Answer (score 1):

You mix two independent tasks: spex decoding and resampling. The mentioned frame size should be considered only as a buffer that contains PCM samples. These PCM samples you should pass to a resampler (for example SSRC: http://shibatch.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Frame Size depends on the codec used to compress the original data. It will contain an integral number of samples (320 in this case).

If I'm correct in thinking raw audio has a frame size equal to the sample size. However some codecs perform compression over a range of samples. Usually the larger the frame size, the more memory needed to compress the data but the potentially better compression you can achieve.

You can't increase the sampling rate during decoding however you could resample the decoded audio. Presumably you're actually re-encoding the data to send it to Flex? You'll need to have a look at the codec you're using to rencode. Which codec are you using?

Answer (score 0):

irrespective of number of channels used, frame rate and sampling rate are same.
because that is the purpose of TDM.
New channels are introduced in the gap left between two consecutive samples.
As the number of channels increase time allotted to each channel decrease there by time taken by each bit.
but tame gap between consecutive samples of any channel will remain constant and it will equal to the total frame time.
i.e. Time gap between samples = Frame time, hence Frame rate is equal to sample rate.